# JRootPane Default Button not Rendered Correctly with Mac OS X LAF when Resized

Tags: java, macos, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

**Goal:** To create a default button with the mac OS X LAF. To do this I used the `setDefaultButton(JButton)` method on a `JFrame`s `JRootPane`.

**Problem:** When I resize the `JFrame` to be larger than the default button's preferred size, the button looks like a regular `JButton`. If the `JFrame` is returned to somewhere around its original size, the button goes back to looking like it's a default button. This *does not* happen with any other of the default LAFs.

**Example GIFs**:

Metal:                                                            Mac OS X:
[image: Metal Default Button GIF][image: Mac OS X Defauly Button GIF]

**Question:** How can I have a default button with the Mac OS X LAF that resizes without changing appearence?

**Code:** A `JOptionPane` will ask you to choose one of your installed LAFs. Choose one, and a default button with that LAF will be displayed.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ResizingDeafultButtonMCVE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LookAndFeelInfo[] lafs = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
        ArrayList<String> lafNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < lafs.length; i++) {
            lafNames.add(lafs[i].getName());
        }

        Object option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Choose a LAF", "", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                null, lafNames.toArray(new String[0]), 0);

        if(option == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()
                 [lafNames.indexOf(option)].getClassName());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException
                | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame((String) option);

            JButton defaultButton = new JButton("Default Button");
            frame.getContentPane().add(defaultButton);
            frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(defaultButton);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: "_How can I have a default button with the Mac OS X LAF that resizes without changing appearance?"_ The UI delegate manages this; either allow it _or_ write your own delegate _or_ change a requirement.

Comment: @trashgod Thank you for your response, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to know to understand why the below example works:

- An `AquaButtonBorder` draws the button part of a button controlled by an `AquaButtonUI`
- The border drawing code for an `AquaBorder` is done by a `AquaPainter`. Specifically, an `AquaSingleImagePainter` paints an image onto a `Graphics2D` context by using a `JRSUIControl` with a given `JRSUIState`.
- The supplied `JRSUIState` to an `AquaSingleImagePainter` is what is used by the `JRSUIControl` to determine what is painted natively
- A `JRSUIState` is modified by applying `Property`s via `JRSUIState#set(Property)`
- A default button on OS X must be a [push button](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/buttons/push-buttons/) (`Widget.BUTTON_PUSH`, a `Property`)
- The button style property is applied to the `JRSUIState` used to paint the image in `AquaButtonBorder.Dynamic#doButtonPaint(AbstractButton, ButtonModel, Graphics, int, int, int, int)`
- The style `Property` (`Widget`) of a button is determined by 
  `AquaButtonBorder.Dynamic#getStyleForSize(AbstractButton, Size, int, int)`
- Push buttons have a maximum size
- The above method returns `Widget.BUTTON_BEVEL_ROUND` for buttons above the maximum height for a push button (Implemented as `SizeConstants.fNormalButtonHeight + 3 = 32`)

Therefore, to have a default button always appear default regardless of size, `getStyleForSize(...)` must always return `Widget.BUTTON_PUSH` for default buttons.

**Solution:**

1. Subclass `AquaButtonBorder.Dynamic` and override the `getStyleForSize(...)` to return `Widget.BUTTON_PUSH` if the given `AbstractButton` is a default button (The button's `JRootPane`'s default button is itself), as shown below:

   ```
   public class AlwaysDefaultAquaButtonBorder extends AquaButtonBorder.Dynamic {

       @Override
       protected JRSUIConstants.Widget getStyleForSize(final AbstractButton b, 
                                                   final JRSUIConstants.Size size,
                                                   final int width, 
                                                   final int height) {
           if(b != null && b.getRootPane() != null 
               && Objects.equals(b, b.getRootPane().getDefaultButton())) {
               return JRSUIConstants.Widget.BUTTON_PUSH;
           }
           return super.getStyleForSize(b, size, width, height);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Set your button's border to a new instance of this custom border *after* it has been added to its parent component, otherwise the border will be reset to the UI-default value by `AquaButtonUI` because of a hierarchy change when it is added to its parent

**Note:** The resulting default button border will not fill the button's bounds because push buttons have a maximum height. The height of the drawn border will remain constant and centered vertically as the button's height grows.

**Full example:**

```
import apple.laf.JRSUIConstants;
import com.apple.laf.AquaButtonBorder;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AquaAlwaysDefaultButtonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aqua Always Default Button Example");
            final JButton defaultButton = new JButton("Default Button");
            frame.getContentPane().add(defaultButton);
            defaultButton.setBorder(new AlwaysDefaultAquaButtonBorder());
            frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(defaultButton);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static class AlwaysDefaultAquaButtonBorder extends AquaButtonBorder.Dynamic {

        @Override
        protected JRSUIConstants.Widget getStyleForSize(final AbstractButton b,
                                                        final JRSUIConstants.Size size,
                                                        final int width,
                                                        final int height) {
            if(b != null && b.getRootPane() != null
                    && Objects.equals(b, b.getRootPane().getDefaultButton())) {
                return JRSUIConstants.Widget.BUTTON_PUSH;
            }
            return super.getStyleForSize(b, size, width, height);
        }

    }

}
```

[image: gif of above full example]